# Book series where the characters are trying to get the last parts of sentient dragon armour

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

The series has many parallel worlds. There are four books, and all but the last are called "dragon-something". They are trying to get the last parts of this dragon armour that is sentient. Swords are the main weapon; they see a gun in one world and are confused as the bullet is blunt.  The main character is disguised as a girl. It is titled *The J(something) Chronicles* and written by Paul (someone).

Comment: swords are the main weapon they see a gun in 1 world and are confused as the bullet is blunt

Comment: When would these have been written?  (Or at least when did you read them?)

Comment: i found them when browsing through my borrowing history

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Self-answers must wait 48 hours, but it looks like that time has passed.

Comment: I have closed your question as a Duplicate, and we have an older, more complete, answer about this series. You will still get points for upvotes on the question and answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Dragonlinks](https://paulcollins.com.au/pauls-books/dragonlinks/) The Jelindel Chronicles writing this post helped me remember by Paul Collins

> An all-powerful, enchanted mailshirt from the stars.
>
> Six links are missing.
>
> An orphan, a streetwise urchin and a swordsman must
> find the links before the greatest evil known descends upon Q’zar.
>
> Jelindel dek Mediesar led a charmed life until lindrak
> assassins murdered her family. Fleeing to the markets Jelindel dresses
> as a boy to avoid detection. Here she teams up with Zimak, a
> street-wise urchin, and Daretor, a warrior on a quest to destroy an
> alien artifact.
>
> Murder, betrayal and deceit are just some of the
> hurdles they must face in order to find the missing links from a
> star-dwellers' mailshirt— six powerful links, whose individual powers
> are nothing compared with that of the complete mailshirt.